# How to use variable as table name in SQL command

Tags: vb.net

Please help, thanks: parameterized queries for SQL Server
Say we have a list with two items, list(0) = "tablename1", list(1) = "tablename2"
How can we pass list(0) or list(1) to sqlcommand such as "Select * from @list(0)"? The error is something about declaration on @Name which I do not know.

Pseudocode is below:

```
1.  strQuery = "Select * From @Name"
2.   
3.          sqlSQLCon = New SqlConnection(strSQLConn)
4.   
5.          Dim sqlSQLCommand As New SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlSQLCon)
6.   
7.          sqlSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", list(0))
8.   
9.              
10.         sqlSQLCon.Open()
11.  
12.         Dim sqlSQLReader As SqlDataReadersqlSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
13.  
14.         If sqlSQLReader.HasRows Then
               Do something
            End If
```

Comment: Just so you know, although it looks temptingly easy to use, [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: It would be prudent to use `SELECT * FROM QUOTENAME(" & list(0) &")`: [when/why would you use QUOTENAME ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40616822/1115360)

Comment: Please quote error messages verbatim in your posts - `something about` simply doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters for identifiers (table names, column names, etc) in SQL code; only for values. You have no choice but to use string concatenation. For that reason, you have to be very careful about where the table name comes from. Ideally, you would query the database to get the table names and then have the user select one from that list. That way, you're guaranteed that no malicious SQL can be injected.

Comment: I did use code to get a list of table names and put in a list. Please give me some codes on CommandText and CommandType, thanks

Comment: Example added, although I'm not sure why you needed me to demonstrate how to set a couple of properties. The very first thing you should have done was go and read the documentation for those properties for yourself. ALWAYS do all you can for yourself before asking others to do for you.

Comment: From MS docs "TableDirect is only supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Mary, bugger! Didn't see that. Never actually tried to use it myself. I'll remove that part from my answer.